# Best practices of phpunit in a complex scenario

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm trying to test my php cms and I question many things about why & how:

- official policy is **NOT** to test protected/private methods

but then it's about functional/behavioral testing and not unit testing

- development of phpunit stopped support of database testing a whole time ago; sth they called it `dbunit` if I remember right

as a result we do have to create complex test classes for database management or because these classes already exist in an extensive work like mine we do have to use methods from other classes existed here and there that facilitate database management so the system under test actually helps the testing software in a close interaction one with the other

- it is said that testing is actually call your code before even having written it using your awesome command line and move step-by-step to your goal

but if your testing <s>code</s> targets a more functional approach then I can call my in-development method with any other way even from command line and debug it sending output to php log with `error_log`.

Having said that I save all the trouble of writing 100 lines of code + more than 100 lines of test files, changing 100 lines of code + changing more than 100 lines of test files and on and on....

In the above if we add all the arguments about not to test protected/private members we end in a simple question: why that fuss on unit testing of private/protected methods that might have long chain of internal calls when there are much simpler methods of testing while we code?

All the above introduction seems to me necessary for the reader to understand what I'm asking about:

**Given the next specific method can you propose the best approach of (unit?) testing?**

## 1 Method under test

File is `/home/test/server/auth/Auth.php`

```
namespace g3\auth;

use g3\Singleton;
use g3\TokenFactory;
use g3\Registry;
use g3\Header;
use g3\Session;
use g3\Lang;
use g3\Utils;
use g3\mail\MailClient;
use Firebase\JWT;

class Auth {
   /** @var AuthToken $token The AuthToken of this class */
   protected $token;
   /** @var PDO $dbh The PDO handler to the database */
   protected $dbh;
...............
...............
   /**
    * Called by user/admin during the registration.
    * 
    * We use argument '$params' to handle the additional fields that we added at 
    * table 'profiles' (beyond, 'id', 'emai', 'password', 'isactive' and 'dt'). 
    * An example for '$params': array('first_name' => "John", 'second_name' => "Doe").
    * The available fields:
    * - 'title', 
    * - 'fullname',
    * - 'first_name',
    * - 'second_name',
    * - 'username',
    * - 'address1',
    * - 'address2',
    * - 'zip1',
    * - 'zip2',
    * - 'tel',
    * - 'mobile',
    * - 'fax',
    * - 'city',
    * - 'state',
    * - 'country',
    * - 'birth',
    * - 'language',
    * - 'currency',
    * - 'img',
    * - 'capacity_kb'.
    * 
    * Two modes of call:
    * -by user: addUser($email, $password, $params, $name),
    * -by admin: addUser($email, $password, $params, $name, true).
    * 
    * In admin mode no request is added or email is sent.
    * 
    * If useradd succeeds but profile fails to be inserted in table 'profiles' 
    * then return array contains key 'message' although key 'error' remains 
    * 'false' (registration proceeds).
    * 
    * @param string $email
    * @param string $password
    * @param string[] $params Data for table 'profiles'
    * @param boolean $admin True to bypass activation process
    * 
    * @return A hash array with keys 'error', 'message' and if successful, 'uid'
    */
   protected function addUser($email, $password, $params = array(), $name = '', $admin = false) {
      $return['error'] = true;
      $query = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO {$this->token->get('table_users')} (isactive) VALUES (0)");
      if (!$query->execute()) {
         $return['message'] = $this->getLang()["system_error"] . " #03";
         return $return;
      }
      $uid = $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
      $email = \htmlentities(\strtolower($email));
      if (((int)$this->token->get('suppress_activation') != 1) && !$admin) {
         $addRequest = $this->addRequest($uid, $email, "activation", $name);
         if ($addRequest['error'] == 1) {
            $query = $this->dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM {$this->token->get('table_users')} WHERE id = ?");
            $query->execute(array($uid));
            $return['message'] = $addRequest['message'];
            return $return;
         }
         $isactive = 0;
      } else {
         $isactive = 1;
      }
      $password = $this->getHash($password);
      $query = $this->dbh->prepare("UPDATE {$this->token->get('table_users')} SET email = ?, password = ?, isactive = ? WHERE id = ?");
      if (!$query->execute(array($email, $password, $isactive, $uid))) {
         $query = $this->dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM {$this->token->get('table_users')} WHERE id = ?");
         $query->execute(array($uid));
         $return['message'] = $this->getLang()["system_error"] . " #04";
         return $return;
      }
      if (!\is_array($params))
         $params = array();
      if(($r = $this->addProfile($uid, $params)) !== true)
         $return['message'] = $r['message'];
      $return['error'] = false;
      $return['uid'] = $uid;
      return $return;
   }
.............
.............
}
```

Database is SQLite.

It's obvious that a numerous other methods of `class Auth` are called:

```
Auth::addUser
  | | | |
  v | | |
Auth::getLang
    | | |
    v | |
Auth::addRequest
      | |
      v |
Auth::getHash
        |
        v
Auth::addProfile
```

Also a number of other classes are used:

```
class Auth
  | | |
  v | |
Auth::token is a AuthToken: contains parameters supporting the 
authentication system like table names, database path etc.
    | |
    v |
class Lang: contains parameters that lead to language specific 
messages
      |
      v
Auth::dbh is a database connection returned by DbHandler::getHandler
class DbHandler: manages the database
```

**You can skip next parts and read "5. Write some tests"**

## 2 Setup Composer

- just download a local `composer.phar`
- build a `composer.json`: I don't care about composer's autoloader as I have mine and I load it there from my `/home/test/server/g3` sub-folder
- I don't use `vendor` but only for developing packages all production software including my `g3` framework are deployed on `/home/test/server` sub-folder on seperate sub-folders with a custom autoloader

***/home/test/composer.json***

```
{
   "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
         "": "server"
      }
    },
   "require-dev": {
         "mockery/mockery": "=1.3.1",
         "phpunit/phpunit": "=6.5.14",
         "phpunit/php-invoker": "=1.1.4",
         "gealex/doublit": "=2.1.5",
         "phpspec/prophecy": "=1.10.3"
    }
}
```

***/home/test/vendor/autoloader.php***

```
<?php

// my autoloader
require_once("/home/test/server/g3/ClassLoader.php");

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit1e0ee11cc0a18a5af0d236383dd8a888::getLoader();
```

## 3 Setup phpunit

- just download a local `/home/test/server/dev/phpunit-6.phar`
- customize the `/home/test/server/dev/phpunit.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="/home/test/vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
         verbose="true">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Root">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">../../tests/server/root</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Core">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">../../tests/server/core</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Auth">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">../../tests/server/auth</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="mail">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">../../tests/server/mail</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">server</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <php>
        <var name="skip_mail_integration_tests" value="1"/>
        <var name="skip_auth_integration_tests" value="1"/>
        <var name="domain" value="4f4d4ebc35f1.eu.ngrok.io"/>
        <var name="mailTo" value="john.doe@gmail.com"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

## 4 Extend PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase

First let's extend `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` with `/home/test/tests/server/CustomTestCase.php` that

- supports `Prophecy` and `Mockery`
- contains utility methods `callMethod`, `getProperty` and `setProperty` that can access private/protected members
- initializes `\g3\Registry` with real `\g3\Token` values coming from json files

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use Mockery\Adapter\Phpunit\MockeryTestCase;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

/**
 * runTestsInSeparateProcesses
 */
class CustomTestCase extends MockeryTestCase {
   protected $prophet;
   
   // returns the call to private/protected methods
   public static function callMethod($obj, $name, array $args) {
      $class = new \ReflectionClass($obj);
      $method = $class->getMethod($name);
      $method->setAccessible(true);
      return $method->invokeArgs($obj, $args);
   }
   // returns private/protected properties
   public static function getProperty($obj, $name){
      $r = new ReflectionObject($obj);
      $p = $r->getProperty($name);
      $p->setAccessible(true);
      return $p->getValue($obj);
      // alternative syntax with closures
      //$cls = \Closure::bind(function() use ($name){return $this->{$name};}, $obj, \get_class($obj));
      //return $cls();
   }
   // sets a value to a private/protected property
   public static function setProperty($object, $property, $value){
       $ref = new \ReflectionClass($object);
       $ref_prop = $ref->getProperty($property);
       $ref_prop->setAccessible(true);
       $ref_prop->setValue($object, $value);
   }
   
   public static function setUpBeforeClass(){
      Mockery::globalHelpers();
   }
   public static function tearDownAfterClass(){
   }
   
   protected function setup() {
      $this->prophet = new \Prophecy\Prophet;
   }
   protected function tearDown() {
      $this->prophet->checkPredictions();
      Mockery::close();
   }
}
```

## 5 Write some tests

File is `/home/test/tests/server/g3/auth/AuthTest.php`

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../CustomTestCase.php');

/**
 * runTestsInSeparateProcesses
 */
class AuthTest extends CustomTestCase {
   protected $tokens;
   
   public static function setUpBeforeClass(){
      parent::setUpBeforeClass();
      // tokens initialize the g3 framework and these contain full data 
      // from json files; access them like: 
      // \g3\Registry::getInstance()->getToken('g3\auth\AuthToken') etc.
      static::callMethod(\g3\Dispatcher::getInstance(), 'tokenInit', array());
   }
   public static function tearDownAfterClass(){
      parent::tearDownAfterClass();
      \g3\Registry::getInstance()->destroy();
   }
   
   /**
    * Creates mocked constructor argument objects before each test.
    * These tokens do not contain data read from json files; dummy tokens.
    * Accessible through $this->tokens.
    */
   protected function setup() {
      parent::setup();
      
      $resolverToken = $this->getMockBuilder('\g3\ResolverToken')
         ->disableOriginalConstructor()
         ->getMock();
      
      $requestToken = $this->getMockBuilder('\g3\RequestToken')
         ->disableOriginalConstructor()
         ->getMock();
      
      $authToken = $this->getMockBuilder('\g3\auth\AuthToken')
         ->disableOriginalConstructor()
         ->getMock();
      
      $accountToken = $this->getMockBuilder('\g3\AccountToken')
         ->disableOriginalConstructor()
         ->getMock();
      
      $dbh = $this->getMockBuilder('\g3\DbHandler')
         ->disableOriginalConstructor()
         ->getMock();
      
      $lang = $this->getMockBuilder('\g3\Lang')
         ->disableOriginalConstructor()
         ->getMock();
      
      $session = $this->getMockBuilder('\g3\Session')
         ->disableOriginalConstructor()
         ->getMock();
      
      $this->tokens = array('accountToken' => $accountToken, 'resolverToken' => $resolverToken, 'requestToken' => $requestToken, 'authToken' => $authToken, 'dbh' => $dbh, 'lang' => $lang, 'session' => $session);
   }
   
   /**
    * Deletes mocked objects stored at $this->tokens after each test.
    */
   protected function tearDown() {
      parent::tearDown();
      $this->tokens = null;
   }
   
   /**
    * Prints a message on CLI
    */
   public function out($msg){
      $msg = \str_replace(array('test_', '_', "\n"), array('', ' ', ":\n"), $msg);
      fwrite(STDOUT, $msg);
   }

   /**
    * Adds an inactive user. It uses real tokens.
    */
   public function helper_addUserInactive($arr) {
      // AuthToken is not stored in Registry & not synchronized
      \g3\TokenFactory::getInstance()->synchronize($arr['authToken'], 'r');
      $test = $this->getMockBuilder('\g3\auth\Auth')
         ->setConstructorArgs(array($arr['resolverToken'], $arr['requestToken'], $arr['authToken'], $arr['accountToken'], $arr['dbh']))
         ->setMethods(['addRequest', 'getHash'])
         ->getMock();
      $test->expects($this->exactly(1))
         ->method('addRequest')
         ->will($this->returnValue(array('error' => false)));
      $test->expects($this->exactly(1))
         ->method('getHash')
         ->will($this->returnValue('123'));
      $token = static::getProperty($test, 'token');
      $token->set('suppress_activation', 0);
      $profile = array('first_name' => 'John', 'second_name' => 'Doe', 'username' => 'John', 'address1' => 'White House, Washington D.C.', 'country' => 'USA');
      // call 'addUser'
      $r = static::callMethod($test, 'addUser', array($arr['to'], '123', $profile, 'John'));
      $users = $arr['authToken']->get('table_users');
      $profiles = $arr['authToken']->get('table_profiles');
      
      return array(
         'dbh' => $arr['dbh'], 
         'user' => array('id' => $r['uid'], 'email' => $arr['to'], 'password' => '123', 'role' => 'guest', 'isactive' => '0'), 
         'profile' => $profile, 
         'tables' => array('users' => $arr['authToken']->get('table_users'), 'profiles' => $arr['authToken']->get('table_profiles'), 'requests' => $arr['authToken']->get('table_requests'))
      );
   }

/**
    * Adds an active user. It uses real tokens.
    */
   public function helper_addUserActive($arr) {
      // AuthToken is not stored in Registry & not synchronized
      \g3\TokenFactory::getInstance()->synchronize($arr['authToken'], 'r');
      $test = $this->getMockBuilder('\g3\auth\Auth')
         ->setConstructorArgs(array($arr['resolverToken'], $arr['requestToken'], $arr['authToken'], $arr['accountToken'], $arr['dbh']))
         ->setMethods(['addRequest', 'getHash'])
         ->getMock();
      $test->expects($this->never())
         ->method('addRequest');
      $test->expects($this->exactly(1))
         ->method('getHash')
         ->will($this->returnValue('123'));
      $token = static::getProperty($test, 'token');
      $token->set('suppress_activation', 1);
      $profile = array('first_name' => 'John', 'second_name' => 'Doe', 'username' => 'John', 'address1' => 'White House, Washington D.C.', 'country' => 'USA');
      // call 'addUser'
      $r = static::callMethod($test, 'addUser', array($arr['to'], '123', $profile, 'John'));
      $users = $arr['authToken']->get('table_users');
      $profiles = $arr['authToken']->get('table_profiles');
      
      return array(
         'dbh' => $arr['dbh'], 
         'user' => array('id' => $r['uid'], 'email' => $arr['to'], 'password' => '123', 'role' => 'guest', 'isactive' => '1'), 
         'profile' => $profile, 
         'tables' => array('users' => $arr['authToken']->get('table_users'), 'profiles' => $arr['authToken']->get('table_profiles'), 'requests' => $arr['authToken']->get('table_requests'))
      );
   }
   
   /**
    * Adds an active user as admin. It uses real tokens.
    */
   public function helper_adminAddsUserActive($arr) {
      // AuthToken is not stored in Registry & not synchronized
      \g3\TokenFactory::getInstance()->synchronize($arr['authToken'], 'r');
      $test = $this->getMockBuilder('\g3\auth\Auth')
         ->setConstructorArgs(array($arr['resolverToken'], $arr['requestToken'], $arr['authToken'], $arr['accountToken'], $arr['dbh']))
         ->setMethods(['addRequest', 'getHash'])
         ->getMock();
      $test->expects($this->never())
         ->method('addRequest');
      $test->expects($this->exactly(1))
         ->method('getHash')
         ->will($this->returnValue('123'));
      $token = static::getProperty($test, 'token');
      $token->set('suppress_activation', 0);
      $profile = array('first_name' => 'John', 'second_name' => 'Doe', 'username' => 'John', 'address1' => 'White House, Washington D.C.', 'country' => 'USA');
      // call 'addUser'
      $r = static::callMethod($test, 'addUser', array($arr['to'], '123', $profile, 'John', true));
      $users = $arr['authToken']->get('table_users');
      $profiles = $arr['authToken']->get('table_profiles');
      
      return array(
         'dbh' => $arr['dbh'], 
         'user' => array('id' => $r['uid'], 'email' => $arr['to'], 'password' => '123', 'role' => 'guest', 'isactive' => '1'), 
         'profile' => $profile, 
         'tables' => array('users' => $arr['authToken']->get('table_users'), 'profiles' => $arr['authToken']->get('table_profiles'), 'requests' => $arr['authToken']->get('table_requests'))
      );
   }
   
   /**
    * Inserts a user & profile without the call to any `Auth` method.
    * It uses real tokens.
    */
   public function helper_insertUser($arr, $active = '0') {
      // AuthToken is not stored in Registry & not synchronized
      \g3\TokenFactory::getInstance()->synchronize($arr['authToken'], 'r');
      $users = $arr['authToken']->get('table_users');
      $profiles = $arr['authToken']->get('table_profiles');
      $requests = $arr['authToken']->get('table_requests');
      // table 'users'
      $time = \time();
      $query = $arr['dbh']->getHandler()->prepare("INSERT INTO {$users} (email, password, isactive, dt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
      $query->execute(array($arr['to'], '123', $active, $time));
      $uid = $arr['dbh']->getHandler()->lastInsertId();
      return array(
         'dbh' => $arr['dbh'], 
         'user' => array('id' => $uid, 'email' => $arr['to'], 'password' => '123', 'role' => 'guest', 'isactive' => $active),  
         'tables' => array('users' => $users, 'profiles' => $profiles, 'requests' => $requests)
      );
   }

   /**
    * Deletes user from tables `users`, `profiles` and `requests`.
    * `$arr` is the return of `::test_helper_addUserInactive` or 
    * `::test_helper_addUserActive`.
    */
   public function helper_deleteAddedUser($arr) {
      $users = $arr['tables']['users'];
      $profiles = $arr['tables']['profiles'];
      $requests = $arr['tables']['requests'];
      $query = $arr['dbh']->getHandler()->prepare("DELETE FROM {$users} WHERE id = ?");
      $query->execute(array($arr['user']['id']));
      $query = $arr['dbh']->getHandler()->prepare("DELETE FROM {$profiles} WHERE uid = ?");
      $query->execute(array($arr['user']['id']));
      $query = $arr['dbh']->getHandler()->prepare("DELETE FROM {$requests} WHERE uid = ?");
      $query->execute(array($arr['user']['id']));
   }

   /**
    * Helper that returns real tokens of g3 platform.
    * @group integration_email
    * @group test
    */
   public function test_helper_construct_with_real_tokens() {
      $systemToken = \g3\Registry::getInstance()->getToken('g3\SystemToken');
      $accountToken = \g3\Registry::getInstance()->getToken('g3\AccountToken');
      $lang = new \g3\Lang(ROOT . "/server/g3/auth/language", $accountToken->get('site', 'language'));
      $exceptionToken = \g3\Registry::getInstance()->getToken('g3\ExceptionToken');
      $dbh = new \g3\DbHandler('sqlite', 'db_auth', $accountToken, $exceptionToken);
      // AuthToken is not stored in Registry & not synchronized
      $authToken = \g3\TokenFactory::getInstance()->getToken('g3\auth\AuthToken', null, array('registry' => \g3\Registry::getInstance(), 'dbh' => $dbh));
      \g3\TokenFactory::getInstance()->synchronize($authToken, 'r');
      $requestToken = \g3\Registry::getInstance()->getToken('g3\RequestToken');
      $resolverToken = \g3\Registry::getInstance()->getToken('g3\ResolverToken');
      $session = \g3\Session::getInstance();
      $to = $GLOBALS['mailTo'];
      
      $this->assertTrue(true);
      
      return array('systemToken' => $systemToken, 'accountToken' => $accountToken, 'resolverToken' => $resolverToken, 'requestToken' => $requestToken, 'authToken' => $authToken, 'exceptionToken' => $exceptionToken, 'dbh' => $dbh, 'lang' => $lang, 'session' => $session, 'to' => $to);
   }

   // !!!WAIT WHAT THE HELL!!!
   // !!!WE DIDN'T EVEN BEGIN TO TEST!!!

   /*
    * ===============
    * Auth::addUser()
    * ===============
    */
   /**
    * @depends test_helper_construct_with_real_tokens
    */
   public function test_addUser_for_misspelled_table_users($arr) {
      $this->out(__METHOD__ . "\n");
      // AuthToken is not stored in Registry & not synchronized
      \g3\TokenFactory::getInstance()->synchronize($arr['authToken'], 'r');
      $test = $this->getMockBuilder('\g3\auth\Auth')
         ->setConstructorArgs(array($arr['resolverToken'], $arr['requestToken'], $arr['authToken'], $arr['accountToken'], $arr['dbh']))
         ->setMethods(null)
         ->getMock();
      $token = static::getProperty($test, 'token');
      $token->set('table_users', 'user');
      // call 'addUser'
      $this->expectException(PDOException::class);
      $r = static::callMethod($test, 'addUser', array($arr['to'], '123', array(), 'John'));
      echo "\n";
   }
   /**
    * @depends test_helper_construct_with_real_tokens
    */
   public function test_addUser_updates_tables_users_profiles($tokens) {
      $this->out(__METHOD__ . "\n");
      $arr = $this->helper_addUserInactive($tokens);
      $users = $arr['tables']['users'];
      $profiles = $arr['tables']['profiles'];
      // query table 'users'
      $query = $arr['dbh']->getHandler()->prepare("SELECT email, role, password, isactive FROM $users WHERE id = ?");
      $query->execute(array($arr['user']['id']));
      $row = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $this->assertSame($arr['user']['email'], $row['email']);
      $this->assertSame($arr['user']['role'], $row['role']);
      $this->assertSame($arr['user']['password'], $row['password']);
      $this->assertSame($arr['user']['isactive'], $row['isactive']);
      // query table 'profiles'
      $query = $arr['dbh']->getHandler()->prepare("SELECT first_name, second_name, username, address1 FROM $profiles WHERE uid = ?");
      $query->execute(array($arr['user']['id']));
      $row = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $this->assertSame($arr['profile']['first_name'], $row['first_name']);
      $this->assertSame($arr['profile']['second_name'], $row['second_name']);
      $this->assertSame($arr['profile']['username'], $row['username']);
      $this->assertSame($arr['profile']['address1'], $row['address1']);
      // delete entries in tables
      $this->test_helper_deleteAddedUser($arr);
      echo "\n";
   }
   /**
    * @depends test_helper_construct_with_real_tokens
    */
   public function test_addUser_updates_tables_users_profiles_with_supress_activation($tokens) {
      $this->out(__METHOD__ . "\n");
      $arr = $this->helper_addUserActive($tokens);
      $users = $arr['tables']['users'];
      $profiles = $arr['tables']['profiles'];
      // query table 'users'
      $query = $arr['dbh']->getHandler()->prepare("SELECT email, role, password, isactive FROM $users WHERE id = ?");
      $query->execute(array($arr['user']['id']));
      $row = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $this->assertSame($arr['user']['email'], $row['email']);
      $this->assertSame($arr['user']['role'], $row['role']);
      $this->assertSame($arr['user']['password'], $row['password']);
      $this->assertSame($arr['user']['isactive'], $row['isactive']);
      // query table 'profiles'
      $query = $arr['dbh']->getHandler()->prepare("SELECT first_name, second_name, username, address1 FROM $profiles WHERE uid = ?");
      $query->execute(array($arr['user']['id']));
      $row = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $this->assertSame($arr['profile']['first_name'], $row['first_name']);
      $this->assertSame($arr['profile']['second_name'], $row['second_name']);
      $this->assertSame($arr['profile']['username'], $row['username']);
      $this->assertSame($arr['profile']['address1'], $row['address1']);
      // delete entries in tables
      $this->test_helper_deleteAddedUser($arr);
      echo "\n";
   }
   /**
    * @depends test_helper_construct_with_real_tokens
    */
   public function test_addUser_updates_tables_users_profiles_for_admin($tokens) {
      $this->out(__METHOD__ . "\n");
      $arr = $this->helper_adminAddsUserActive($tokens);
      $users = $arr['tables']['users'];
      $profiles = $arr['tables']['profiles'];
      // query table 'users'
      $query = $arr['dbh']->getHandler()->prepare("SELECT email, role, password, isactive FROM $users WHERE id = ?");
      $query->execute(array($arr['user']['id']));
      $row = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $this->assertSame($arr['user']['email'], $row['email']);
      $this->assertSame($arr['user']['role'], $row['role']);
      $this->assertSame($arr['user']['password'], $row['password']);
      $this->assertSame($arr['user']['isactive'], $row['isactive']);
      // query table 'profiles'
      $query = $arr['dbh']->getHandler()->prepare("SELECT first_name, second_name, username, address1 FROM $profiles WHERE uid = ?");
      $query->execute(array($arr['user']['id']));
      $row = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $this->assertSame($arr['profile']['first_name'], $row['first_name']);
      $this->assertSame($arr['profile']['second_name'], $row['second_name']);
      $this->assertSame($arr['profile']['username'], $row['username']);
      $this->assertSame($arr['profile']['address1'], $row['address1']);
      // delete entries in tables
      $this->test_helper_deleteAddedUser($arr);
      echo "\n";
   }
```

I just tested sth I knew from the beginning - several months ago - it was working o'right as I can send GET or POST requests and with injected `error_log` I have production error-free code bypassing all unit-testing theories.

Also these tests are prone to error if someone starts messing with the testing method they start producing code errors from the test file; in that case you have to debug the tests that try to test your code!

**From my point of view I start to believe that unit-testing is an excellent way to waste <s>loose</s> your time.** I understand your argument that this is not unit testing so I replace `protected` with `public` does that fixes anything?
I wonder can someone prove me wrong? What's your approach then?

Comment: This seems like a HUGE post to go through to try and understand what you are asking and makes it difficult to provide a specific answer and not just an opinion. Unit testing is about being able to check your code does as expected and also doesn't fail when you send it garbage.  This then can be used when you want to verify that changes haven't broken your existing working code.  Testing is also only as good as what is written, it's easy to write a test for code you have written to prove it's right, but doesn't mean it's working properly.

Comment: I forgot to add my final argument: based on open-close principle your/my code is closed, the tests are done, if someone wants to extend it and find an error your/my tests haven't found it so far so they are useless - we need to debug!

Comment: the method under test is under (1) in my post where I explain what that method does; my post is about how someone would approach a unit testing of that method

Comment: Adding all of the details about setting up composer, phpunit etc. is too much detail, it gets in the way of explaining your problem (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

My approach is the same as the approach I take when solving certain problem/task - break it into as much smaller peaces as possible and solve them one by one.

If I have to test an advanced class and make sure all its methods cover certain criterias, I would make a tests for every method of it even if it is private or protected (with closure functions). So the next time something throws an error/does not pass a test, you know exactly what it is and why it fails.

Comment: so if we need tests to know what it breaks we certainly need to debug next time & NOT to test; tests seem to me more proof-it-works as said someone also useless idea as the end product is a proof it works - just thinking...

Comment: Yes, proof it works, but also next time you have your code based changed, you run the tests to make sure everything works instead of manually testing your system and clicking on every button (or what ever it is). You usually build the tests once, and the amount you take to build it is far less than the time it takes you to test it manually each time something is changed. So you end up saving a lot of time in the long run.